# Python: How to stop getting variable in function after calling function?

Tags: variables, declaration, kill

def one():

```
global onevar
onevar = 'variable one'

print(onevar)
```

def two():

```
twovar = 'variable two'
print(onevar)
```

onebtn = Button(window,text='One' ,command=one)
onebtn.grid(row=0,column=0)

twobtn = Button(window,text='Two' ,command=two)
twobtn.grid(row=0,column=1)

Answer (score 0):

def one():
    global onevar
    onevar = 'variable one'
    print(onevar)

def two():
    twovar = 'variable two'
    print(onevar)

onebtn = Button(window,text='One' ,command=one)
onebtn.grid(row=0,column=0)

twobtn = Button(window,text='Two' ,command=two)
twobtn.grid(row=0,column=1)